# No way to click on a checkbox using selenium with Java

Tags: java, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my HTML element

```
<div _ngcontent-rju-c99="" class="mb-5 custom-control custom-checkbox">
       <input _ngcontent-rju-c99="" required="" type="checkbox" id="tosAccept" name="tosAccept" 
       angularticslabel="AcceptCgu" angularticsvalue="tosAccepted ? 'accepted' : 'notAccepted'" 
       class="custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"> ==$0
       <label _ngcontent-rju-c99="" for="tosAccept" class="custom-control-label">Acepto las 
           <a href="some link" target="_blank">condiciones generales de uso</a>
      </label>
</div>
```

I want to click on the input, which is a checkbox that enable a button, the problem is that i just can't, tried all selectors possible (id, name, css, by xpath, by name by id ...) nothing works, the fun fact is that input doesn't end ! ( no ) which may cause this problem, but its possible with angular i guess.

Of course i have my timers set (`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated`)

Any solution please ? i'm stuck on this since days

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share the link? Where exactly is the issue? Finding the element? or clicking on the element found?

Comment: it's a staging web application through private link :/
The issue is finding the element not clicking on it

Comment: Are you able to search it in chrome developer console? Also, please check if the input element(or any of its ancestor) is a part of a frame or shadow dom?

Comment: okey i'll try thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved with

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.id("tosAccept"));
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var elem=arguments[0]; setTimeout(function() {elem.click();}, 100)", checkbox);
```